# How to fill an array with data from a database

Tags: database, vb.net, multidimensional-array

I am reading a table from an access database in vb.net. I would like to know how many records are from a certain year. If the year does not exist in the array I like to add it and set the count to 1. When the year already exists in the array I want to increase the count to 2.

For example DOCUMENT1.2019 creates the year 2019 in the array with count 1, then DOCUMENT2.2019 sets the count to 2 for 2019, then DOCUMENT1.2018 creates the year 2018 and sets the count to 1.
and so on.

So I dont know how large the array will be when I start.

```
        Dim sSQL As String
        Dim sGetString As String
        Dim sPartString As String
        sSQL = "SELECT [Document Name] FROM Archief ORDER BY Id DESC"
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sSQL, con)
        Dim read As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If read.HasRows Then
            While read.Read()
                sGetString = read.Item("Document Name").ToString()
                sPartString = Mid(sGetString, Len(sGetString) - 11, 4)  'retrieve the year like 2019
            End While
        End If
```

The endstate will  be  an overview of the years and the amount of documents from that year.
h

Comment: Don't use an array, use a `List(of T)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A connection needs to remain open while a reader is active. You don't want to do a lot of processing while the connection is open.

Commands and DataReaders need to be disposed. Using `Using...End Using blocks takes care of this even if there is an error. Declare and dispose connections in the method where they are used.

Let the database do the work. Access offers some string manipulation functions that you can use in queries. You can also use Count with Group By to get the results you desire.

```
Private Sub GetYearCountData()
    Dim sSQL = "SELECT Right([Document Name],4) As [Year], Count([Year]) FROM Archief  Group By Right([Document Name],4) Order By Right([Document Name],4) ;"
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sSQL, New OleDbConnection(ConStr))
        cmd.Connection.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Comment: Getting the right characters from the table is a little more complicated: DOCUMENT.20190131.PDF Mid(sGetString, Len(sGetString) - 11, 4)

Comment: Access also has a Mid function. Just substitute and set up for Mid. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Working perfectly: Dim sSQL = "SELECT Mid([Document Name], Len([Document Name]) - 11, 4) As [Year], Count([Year]) FROM Archief  Group By Mid([Document Name], Len([Document Name]) - 11, 4) Order By Mid([Document Name], Len([Document Name]) - 11, 4) ;"

Comment: Found out another flaw in the code since some documents have an extension of 4 letters, like .DOCX or PPTX, so the code doesnt extract the right characters

Comment: That is not a flaw in the code. That is a flaw in your question.